# Ubuntu 13.10, nVidia Optimus graphics card appears as a secondary display

Tags: nvidia-optimus, gdm

There are many problems with Optimus, but currently two main problems prevent me from logging in.

First; installing nvidia drivers via official repositories results in a blank screen during login. Purging nvidia seems to solve this.

Second; without nvidia drivers my nvidia VGA appears as a "secondary display". Its resolution is much smaller than it should be. I can't find configuration files to modify those values.

I need to find a way to use nvidia drivers and resize that "secondary display". I'm currently installing Bumblebee to see if it still works.

**EDIT:** using bumblebee gives following error "Cannot access secondary GPU, secondary X is not active."

**EDIT2:** following this guide (with some changes) http://tuxilero.blogspot.cz/2013/09/how-to-official-nvidia-drivers.html I was able to enable nvidia and now the only (minor) problem is that some features like hotkeys and themes aren't working.

BTW: I'm using Gnome 3 and GDM. Unity and LightDM just show the error message asking for further actions (such as run in low-graph environment or restore default settings).

Answer (score 1):

If you want bumblebee install `linux-headers-generic`, `nvidia-319-updates`, `bumblebee` and `bumblebee-nvidia`. For `nvidia-prime` don't install `bumblebee` but install `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-39-updates`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [issues section](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues?state=open) of the [bumblebee github page](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee). A number of different users have the same problem as you (specifically the Cannot Access Secondary GPU problem).

Once you have bumblebee properly setup you should see that most (if not all) of your problems will go away. You can see what is left over to fix and take it from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't help. I was more screwed with that than before. I managed to fix it by removing nvidia, bumblebee and xorg.conf. Using Bumblebee is NOT an option on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I can't understand this because bumblebee on Kubuntu 13.10 works fine for me :/

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo W530 with the nvidia Optimus and I upgraded my nvidia-319-updates drivers to nvidia-331 and it resolved several video display issues. It also appears to be faster display.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me; I was missing the package `bumblebee-nvidia`. When you install NVidia's drivers, they replace your system's `libGL.so` therefore breaking your integrated graphics, which is a Bad Thing(tm) since integrated is what actually runs your display and DE. Installing `bumblebee-nvidia` moves NVidia's `libGL.so` out of the way so integrated can work.

This is not needed for the Nouveau driver, since that driver is happy using the system `libGL.so`.